# Unable to migrate mails to "Trash"

Tags: c#, email, migration, recycle-bin

I am migrating some mails to 'TRASH' in Google Apps.

Using Google API Ver 2:

Code Sample :

```
MailItemEntry[] entries = new MailItemEntry[1];
entries[0]              = new MailItemEntry();
entries[0].Rfc822Msg    = new Rfc822MsgElement(msg);
entries[0].MailItemProperties.Add(MailItemPropertyElement.TRASH);
```

I tried with :

```
entries[0].Labels.Add(new LabelElement("Trash"));
```

How can i migrate mails to "TRASH" in Google Apps ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps or Gmail keeps only Last 30 Days mails in Trash.